# How to access popup menu from hidden system tray icon

Tags: python-3.x, system-tray, pywinauto, popupmenu

I use following code to access hidden icon and to show its popup menu and to click on "Sign Off" menuitem:

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
st = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
t = st.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").wrapper_object()
t.click()
time.sleep(0.25)

list_box = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win = list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
list_box_win.wait('visible', timeout=30, retry_interval=3)
list_box_win.child_window(title="Citrix Workspace").click_input(button='right').menu_item('Sign Out').click_input()
```

Popup menu is shown, but I got error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'menu_item'`

When I tried to add this code (instead of `.menu_item('Sign Out').click_input()`) :

```
connector = Application()
connector.connect(path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Citrix\\ICA Client\\SelfServicePlugin\\SelfService.exe")
connector.PopupMenu.MenuItem("Sign Out").ClickInput()
```

path is reflecting application that responsible for icon in system tray.
I got error: `MatchError: Could not find 'PopupMenu' in 'dict_keys([])'`. So I can I access menuitem in popup window?

BTW: It is run on windows 10 64 bit with python 3.6.

Comment: did you find any solution to this? Because, I am having exactly the same problem!

Comment: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Unpolished/optimized (but working) code looks like this:

```
import pywinauto.application
import time

taskbar = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")

windows_tray = taskbar.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
tray = windows_tray.child_window(title="Notification Chevron").wrapper_object()
tray.click()

time.sleep(1)

app_list_box =  pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")
app_list_box_win = app_list_box.window(class_name="NotifyIconOverflowWindow")

target_app = app_list_box_win.child_window(title = "Citrix Workspace")
target_app.click_input(button = "right")

citrix = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(path='Receiver.exe')
sign = citrix.PopupMenu.menu().get_menu_path("Sign In...")[0]
sign.click_input()
```

Where 'Receiver.exe' is executable of application running in system tray and "Citrix Workspace" title of of it.